# Hibernate performs unnecessary merge between two objects in session (previous and actual)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, primefaces, jpa-2.0

I am not an expert in Hibernate, so this issue breaks my brain.

I wrote a Web application some time ago with

- Primefaces 4.0
- Hibernate 4.2.21.Final (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
  1.0.1.Final)
- Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE
- MySQL

The main purpose of this application - editing a database of clients data in the one organization using a thin Web client.

Workflow is described below:

There is a queue of clients during the working day of Users.

1. Client come to User, Users asks him about his name or ID
2. User use the search and find the client by id or name. Result is shown as `<p:dataTable>` where each row is an object of found Clients list.
3. By selecting the client (`rowKey="#{client.id}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{clientform.client}"`), user sets the property of ManagedBean (ClientForm) with 'Client' type:

ClientFormBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "clientform")
@SessionScoped
    public class ClientFormBean implements Serializable {
        private Client client;
}
```

Here is used SessionScope because User can edit only one client at this time because of some restrictions.

4. Ok. User can change his properties, edit fields with custom information, photo, generate for him some documents etc.

When next client come to User, User go to the step 1 and just find next client etc etc.

It works properly almost always, but, randomly, 1-2 times in a week (or in a two weeks) the most part of previous client's data (only Client type and Client's one-to-many connections) are overwritten with actual client's data (in the ClientFormBean.client) during the persisting operation to database.

I use next DAO method:

```
@Repository
public class GenericDAO implements IGenericService, Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public <T> void updateInstance(T instance) {
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(instance);
    }
}
```

I will appreciate if someone could say me why it happens and how to fix this issue because actually I can't understand how to find way to identify the problem (may be it is the known issue?).

May be it is necessary to disable caching or make evict() any time for the previous object when User loading the new client's data (I don't know how it is possible because Users selects new client using `<p:dataTable>` PrimeFaces selector).

Hibernate properties:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance!

Addition:

Client - is the main entity and Hibernate merges only this entity and its relations (they are POJO classess so I didn't attached them to the question).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String surname;
    private String middlename;
    private String firstname;
    private Set<ChronicDisease> diseases;
    private NightStay nightStay;
    private Education education;
    private Set<Breadwinner> breadwinners;
    private Set<Reasonofhomeless> reasonofhomeless;
    private FamilyCommunication fcom;
    private Set<RecievedService> recievedservices;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,targetEntity = ChronicDisease.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "link_chronicdisease_client", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "clients_id", nullable = false, updatable = false), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "diseases_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
)
    public Set<ChronicDisease> getDiseases() {
        return diseases;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = NightStay.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "nightStay")
    public NightStay getNightstay() {
        return nightStay;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Education.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "education")
    public Education getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,targetEntity =    Breadwinner.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "link_breadwinner_client", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "clients_id", nullable = false, updatable = false), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "breadwinners_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
)
    public Set<Breadwinner> getBreadwinners() {
        return breadwinners;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,targetEntity = Reasonofhomeless.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "link_reasonofhomeless_client", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "clients_id", nullable = false, updatable = false), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reasonofhomeless_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
)
    public Set<Reasonofhomeless> getReasonofhomeless() {
        return reasonofhomeless;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = FamilyCommunication.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "familycommunication")
    public FamilyCommunication getFcom() {
        return fcom;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RecievedService.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client")
    public Set<RecievedService> getRecievedservices() {
        return recievedservices;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SubRegion.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lastLiving")
    public SubRegion getLastLiving() {
        return lastLiving;
    }

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = SubRegion.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lastRegistration")
    public SubRegion getLastRegistration() {
        return lastRegistration;
    }
}
```

And below is the method of ClientFormBean.java which saves changes (and sometimes merge previous data with current to the database):

```
public void saveClientForm() {
    FacesMessage msg;

    if (client != null) {

        HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
        String username = session.getAttribute("username").toString();
        if (homelessDateNotNull) {
            updateHomelessDate(selectedMonth, getSelectedYear());
        } else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(1900,0,1,0,0,0);
            Date nullDate = cal.getTime();
            client.setHomelessdate(nullDate);
        }

        client.setSurname(checkNameDash(client.getSurname()));
        client.setFirstname(checkNameDash(client.getFirstname()));
        client.setMiddlename(checkNameDash(client.getMiddlename()));

            Set<Breadwinner> sb = new HashSet<Breadwinner>();
            for (Breadwinner b : getClientService().getInstances(Breadwinner.class)) {
                for (String cb : clientBreadwinners) {
                    if (b.getCaption().equals(cb)) {
                        sb.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
            client.setBreadwinners(sb);

            Set<Reasonofhomeless> sr = new HashSet<Reasonofhomeless>();
            for (Reasonofhomeless b : getClientService().getInstances(Reasonofhomeless.class)) {
                for (String cb : clientReasonsofhomeless) {
                    if (b.getCaption().equals(cb)) {
                        sr.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
            client.setReasonofhomeless(sr);

            Set<ChronicDisease> chd = new HashSet<ChronicDisease>();
            for (ChronicDisease b : getClientService().getInstances(ChronicDisease.class)) {
                for (String cb : clientChronicDisease) {
                    if (b.getCaption().equals(cb)) {
                        chd.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
            client.setDiseases(chd);

        try {
            getClientService().updateInstance(client);
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Сохранено", "");
            reloadAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Клиент не сохранен!", "");
        }

        if (msg != null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your entities ? Maybe you have a cascade problem or something like this...

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I edited the body of question above and attached the main entity and the method which persists data to database.